# Windows 8 sleep, blank screen on resume

Tags: windows-8, sleep, blank-screen

I use a SONY VAIO laptop VPCS116FA that came pre-installed with Windows 7. I have upgraded to Windows 8. The experience has been good so far but I am facing a frustrating problem. Whenever, I put my computer to sleep, it won't wake up and I have to restart it. Note that this does not affect hibernation which works perfectly fine. However, it is not a perfect alternative to sleep option.

I have tried this method to resolve the problem but in vain:
http://www.thulasidas.com/2009-03/blank-screen-after-hibernatesleep.htm

I really am in need for a solution to this problem. Please suggest whatever you think can resolve this.

Comment: Try disabling hybrid sleep ([Power Options](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-sleep-mode.htm) / Edit Plan Settings / Sleep).

Answer (score 2):

Typically this problem is cause by out-dated video drivers. Ensure that you have the latest video drivers.

1. Get the latest drivers from your Graphics Vendor, or
2. Uninstall the current driver and **Scan for Hardware Changes** in Device Manager.